# How to get the slice-height and stride from a H264 stream?

Tags: android, video, h.264, android-mediacodec

I need the `slice-height` and `stride` information in order to convert the YUV 4:2:0 Planar data to RGB.

Is it inside the SPS/PPS? How do I calculate it?

> SPS = [0, 0, 0, 1, 103, 66, -32, 13, -90, -63, 65, -97, -97, 1, 66, 2,
>   2, 3, -32, 0, 0, 125, 32, 0, 29, 76, 18, -128]
>
> PPS = [0, 0, 0, 1, 104,
>   -50, 49, 18, 0, 0, 1, 6, 0, 1, -64, 6, 1, -124, 1, 1, 4, 4, 10, -75, 0, 49, 68, 84, 71, 49, 65, -8, -1, 83, 4, 64, 0, 2, 7, 93, 18, 0, 0,
>   -94, 58, 0, 0, -94, 58, 0, 2, -102, 55, 0, 0, -100, -128, -128, 21, -128]

The Android `MediaCodec` shows this information after a `MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED`:

> {image-data=java.nio.ByteArrayBuffer[position=0,limit=80,capacity=80],
>   mime=video/raw, crop-top=0, crop-right=319, **slice-height=192**,
>   color-format=21, height=192, width=320, what=1869968451,
>   crop-bottom=179, crop-left=0, **stride=384**}

How do I get this information directly from a H.264 stream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This information is not contained within the coded stream. The concept of stride does not exist in a coded frame. It is purely a decoded image concept, and can be any value equal to or larger than the width.

Comment: Ok, but how do MediaCodec gets this value? Where is it from?

Comment: The MediaCodec software makes up a value. When it decodes the frame, it must allocate a buffer to put the decoded pixel data. It chooses a linesize/stride size larger that width. Usually, the width is rounded up to a multiple of 16 or 32. Some CPU, are more efficient when accessing memory at locations, especially if SSIM instructions are used.